# Python normalise floats in a list of lists to range from 0.0 (smallest) to 1.0 (largest) in each sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Trying to normalize a list of lists I have below:

```
[[7.460143566, 9.373718262, 9.540244102, 9.843519211, 9.034710884, 10.71182728], [0.490880072, 0.637698293, 0.806753874, 0.906699121, 0.697924912, 0.949957848], [52.33952713, 69.05165863, 65.69918823, 67.53870392, 65.12568665, 72.78334045]]
```

into below:

```
[[0.0, 0.3435355, 0.565656, 0.6576767, 1.0], [0.0, 0.232424, 0.465664, 0.76768, 1.0], [0.0, 0.24534535, 0.4564545, 0.576576, 1.0]]
```

I was trying

```
normalized = (col_list_filter-min(col_list_filter))/(max(col_list_filter)-min(col_list_filter))
    print(normalized)
```

But keep getting TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: Please provide a working example program, instead of just a single line that may generate the error in your program, but doesn't really tell the story by itself. One can only assume that the list you provided as an example is the value of `col_list_filter`, which explains the error, since you're going `col_list_filter-min(<etc.>` - you cannot use `-` on a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working on list of lists. So you can use a nested list comprehension:

```
a = [[7.460143566, 9.373718262, 9.540244102, 9.843519211, 9.034710884, 10.71182728], [0.490880072, 0.637698293, 0.806753874, 0.906699121, 0.697924912, 0.949957848], [52.33952713, 69.05165863, 65.69918823, 67.53870392, 65.12568665, 72.78334045]]

b = [[(x-min(l))/(max(l)-min(l)) for x in l] for l in a]

print (b)
```

Result:

```
[[0.0, 0.5884873389626358, 0.6396995276767564, 0.7329666273317014, 0.4842313879485761, 1.0], 
[0.0, 0.3198112142984678, 0.688061628145554, 0.9057703742992778, 0.4510016620800218, 1.0],
[0.0, 0.8174664500409363, 0.6534818573661288, 0.7434609459640676, 0.625429283659689, 1.0]]
```

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly! Hadn't covered comprehension sorry complete newb to Python

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `col_list_filter` is the list of lists, both `col_list_filter-min(col_list_filter)` and `max(col_list_filter)-min(col_list_filter)` are `list - list` just as stated in the error message.

Instead, you can do an element-wise operation using `for` loop:

```
res = []
for i in l:
    max_, min_ = max(i), min(i)
    res.append([(j - min_)/(max_ - min_) for j in i])
res
```

Or one-liner (but much less efficient):

```
[[(j - min(i))/(max(i) - min(i)) for j in i] for i in l]
```

Output:

```
[[0.0,
  0.5884873389626358,
  0.6396995276767564,
  0.7329666273317014,
  0.4842313879485761,
  1.0],
 [0.0,
  0.3198112142984678,
  0.688061628145554,
  0.9057703742992778,
  0.4510016620800218,
  1.0],
 [0.0,
  0.8174664500409363,
  0.6534818573661288,
  0.7434609459640676,
  0.625429283659689,
  1.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Built-in function `max` only recognizes the outermost layer. In this case, it returns the `list`, not numerical value.

I think using Numpy array is much more straight forward.

```py
import numpy as np

your_original_list = [...]
your_numpy_list = np.array(your_original_list)
min_value = your_numpy_list.min()
max_value = your_numpy_list.max()

normalized = (your_numpy_list - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
```

If you want to normalize the list with row-wise, you can specify `axis` parameter.

```
batch = your_numpy_list.shape[0]
min_list = your_numpy_list.min(axis=1).reshape(batch, 1)
max_list = your_numpy_list.max(axis=1).reshape(batch, 1)
normalized = (your_numpy_list - min_list) / (max_list - min_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is some code to normalize just a list of lists:

```
a = [2,4,10,6,8,4]
amin, amax = min(a), max(a)
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = (val-amin) / (amax-amin)
```

credit: https://scipython.com/book/chapter-2-the-core-python-language-i/questions/normalizing-a-list/

Try see if you can try apply this logic to a list of lists.

Give it a go yourself and let me know if you get stuck :)